# Facebook, twitter, youtube livestream on website

Tags: php, facebook, twitter, curl, youtube

I'm trying to create a live stream of comments and disscussions from a twitter, facebook, and youtube page for a social site. Has anyone ever done this before, if so any advice or websites/articles to check out. I'm thinking PHP curl?

Comment: Why use cURL, most of those sites provide APIs.

Comment: @Mike Soule One generally uses cURL to access web APIs.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need permissions from user (application permission request) and then request
https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?access_token=...
where access_token is token returned from facebook after aproving permissions